# accessing a list of tuples in html

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a list of tuples called top_5 which are the top 5 users usernames and their corresponding post count.

This is a list that has 5 items and each item has 2 indexes.

```
{% for user in top_5 %}
   {{ user }}
{% endfor %}
```

returns the user and his post count but is there a way I can get them separately?

Comment: This doesn't look like html or python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a Django template? You can access index values in Django template using the dot notation:

```
{% for user in top_5 %}
    {{ user.0 }} {{ user.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

And as mentioned in the comments, unpacking the tuples is also an option:

```
{% for username, post_count in top_5 %}
    {{ username }} {{ post_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My god. A simple dot. I was using user[0]. Thank you so much.

Comment: Or you can unpack them: `{% for username, post_count in top_5 %}`.